# Unable to install gdal2tiles on PyCharm

Tags: gdal, installation, gdal2tiles, pycharm

I have installed gdal 2.4.1 while installing gdal2tiles. I am getting this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   GDAL==2.4.1 (from gdal2tiles) (from versions: 1.5.0, 1.5.2, 1.6.0,
>   1.6.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.4.0, 2.4.2, 3.0.0, 3.0.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for GDAL==2.4.1 (from gdal2tiles)

Comment: Can you provide some info's about your platform ( Ubuntu 18.04 for example) and how you have installed your toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, 
try to install `pygdal` via pip or pycharm, for me it works!